# Can you have multiple APP_CODE folders in a project

Tags: c#, asp.net, app-code

I inherited this code from another developer (3rd party) but I am implementing it. Its a large website done in c#. For twitter integration they must have created a new website project because the code inside the sub folder has its own `bin` and `app code` folder. This is published on IIS but its a strange setup where it compiles at run time. (If I make a code change to a file on the webserver and save it, it updates instantly without having to publish).

This subdirectory is throwing a 500 error and I assume its because I dont believe you can have multiple `bin` and `app_code` in the same website project. Is that a correct assumption. Should I combinbe all the app_code directories to the one in the root? Here is a more visual example of the directory layout:

```
MyWebsite
App_Code
BIN
 ...other folders and files
MySubdirectory
  App_Code  (ALLOWED??)
  BIN (ALLOWED??)
```

Comment: In asp.net-mvc there is something called area. I recall those had their own binaries/models/views/controllers and stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`App_Code` and `Bin` are special folders only at the root of the application. You should make `MySubdirectory` a child application in IIS.